# Is there a way to display labels in a plot only when clicked on?

Tags: r, plot, label, cluster-analysis, ggrepel

Imagine I have this dataset, data1 (post-scaling and PCA).

```
            F1    F2     F3  F4   F5 ... F21
1          0.28  2.29  5.64 1.04 3.92    1065
2          0.26  1.28  4.38 1.05 3.40    1050
3          0.30  2.81  5.68 1.03 3.17    1185
4          0.24  2.18  7.80 0.86 3.45    1480
5          0.39  1.82  4.32 1.04 2.93     735
.
.
.
1000       0.34  1.97  6.75 1.05 2.85    1450
```

I did a k-means cluster analysis on the dataset using:

```
Clusters <- kmeans(data1, 5, nstart = 25)
data1 <- data.frame(data1)
data1 <- data1 %>% mutate(Cluster = Clusters$cluster)
```

Then I inserted rownames of character type from another dataset:

```
rownames(data1) <- data2$Name
```

Then, to avoid labels overlapping I used

```
p1 <- autoplot(Clusters, data = data1, frame = TRUE, label = F, x=1, y=2)
p2 <- p1 + geom_text_repel(aes(label = rownames(data1)))
```

[image: Which returned this]

Since I have over 500 data points, the labels predictably overlapped and can't be read. I was wondering if there is a method of labeling when the label is only displayed when you click or hover over the data point. Or any other solution is welcome. Thanks

Comment: Please share a reproducible example.

Comment: How do you intend to work with or display interactive graphics? That requires extending this to plotly, rcharts, highcharts, d3, etc. There are lots of options, but we don't know which one you want, which makes this a borderline recommendation question, which is off-topic on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `plotly`. With `add_trace()` you can show a label only on hover.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

data <- mtcars[, c("mpg", "wt")] # just two features

k_data <- kmeans(data, 3) # find clusters
```

Now let's add the cluster info to `data`:

```
data <- cbind(data, cluster=k_data$cluster)
#                mpg    wt cluster
# Mazda RX4     21.0 2.620       1
# Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0 2.875       1
# Datsun 710    22.8 2.320       1
```

Now we can plot everything:

```
plot_ly(data = data, x = ~mpg, y = ~wt, color = ~as.factor(cluster)) %>% 
  add_trace(
    type = 'scatter',
    mode = 'markers',
    text = rownames(data), # when you hover on a point it will show it's rowname
    hoverinfo = 'text',
    showlegend = F
  )
```

[image]

More guides [here](https://plot.ly/r/hover-text-and-formatting/) and [here](https://plot.ly/r/line-and-scatter/).

Comment: When I use this I am only getting a single point on the plot. I can see its label when I hover over it, which is exactly what I wanted to do but something's wrong with the plot itself. I have 21 features in my dataset but when I use x = 1, y = 2 with autoplot, the clusters are displayed correctly

Comment: Don't use `1,2..ecc` for column names, use for example `x1,x2,..`. Then you can use `x = ~x1, y = ~x2`

Comment: I used PCA, that's why it worked with autoplot. I can't adjust it to work for the plot_ly function. I tried x = 1 and y = 2 again but did not seem to work

Comment: See my second comment above, you should name columns differently.

Comment: The 1 and 2 in the example above reference PC1 and PC2 of my PCA. Is naming what is causing it not to work with plot_ly

Comment: I think so, because it's seeing that as numbers not as column names. It's better to avoid plain numbers as column names. Try with `colnames(data) <- paste0("x", colnames(data))` to add a leading `x`. Then use `x=~x1` with `plot_ly`.

Comment: If you use `x=~1`, `plot_ly` won't understand, use the proper column name. By looking at your example data `x=~F1, y=~F2` are the proper names.

Comment: Yes it works like that but that's not what I want. I think it's because ggplot2 and ggfortify can work with PCA objects and that's why when I use x = 1 and y = 2 with autoplot my axes are PCA1 and PCA2. I don't know how to reference the principal components to be used as the axes in plotly.

Comment: Could you please answe here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385588/was-my-edit-wrong-replacing-bit-ly-link-with-the-actual-link